# How do I use tablayout for Android?

Tags: android

i want to Update UI of my App
when i try it with tablayout my app didn't work but when i try it with my previous UI it works
for tab layout i create one tablayout activity & 3 different activity for Weightscale,Bp and pulse oxi .all activities have single service .

Comment: post your code here

Comment: When you get a message saying your question is too short, or missing code, then that doesn't mean repeat half your question

Comment: cricket-007:Sorry for mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        contentReslolver = getContentResolver();
        context = getApplicationContext();

        // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec deviceTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("First tab");

        TabSpec applicationTab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second tab");
        // Set the Tab name and Activity
        // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected


        deviceTab.setIndicator("First");
        deviceTab.setContent(new Intent(this, newclass2.class));

        applicationTab.setIndicator("second");
        applicationTab.setContent(new Intent(this, newclass.class));

        /** Add the tabs to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(homeScreenTab);
        tabHost.addTab(PeripheralTab);
        tabHost.addTab(deviceTab);
        tabHost.addTab(applicationTab);

    }
```

**and you R.layout.main will be**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

        <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
                <TabWidget 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </TabWidget>
                   </HorizontalScrollView>
                <FrameLayout 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Tablayout.java
 public class AllDevicesActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_devices);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Weighing Scale
    TabSpec weighingspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Weighing Scale");
    weighingspec.setIndicator("Weight",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.weighing_icon));
    Intent weightIntent = new Intent(this, WeightScaleActivity.class);
    weighingspec.setContent(weightIntent);
    System.out.println("I am in weightScaleActivity ");

    // Tab for BP Monitor
    TabSpec bpspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("BP");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    bpspec.setIndicator("BP",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bp_monitor_icon));
    Intent bpIntent = new Intent(this, BpActivity.class);
    bpspec.setContent(bpIntent);
    System.out.println("I am in BpActivity ");

    // Tab for Pulse Oximeter
    TabSpec pulsespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Pulse");
    pulsespec.setIndicator("Pulse",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pulse_oxi_icon));
    Intent pulseIntent = new Intent(this, PulseOxiActivity.class);
    pulsespec.setContent(pulseIntent);
    System.out.println("I am in PulseOxiActivity ");

    // Tab for All
    TabSpec alldevicespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("All");
    alldevicespec.setIndicator("All",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pulse_oxi_icon));
    Intent allDeviceIntent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    alldevicespec.setContent(allDeviceIntent);
    System.out.println("I am in AllDevicesActivity ");

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(weighingspec); // Adding Weighing scale tab
    tabHost.addTab(bpspec); // Adding Bp monitor tab
    tabHost.addTab(pulsespec); // Adding Pulse Oxi tab
    tabHost.addTab(alldevicespec); // Adding All Devices tab

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
//tabLayout.xml
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //WeightscaleActivity
   public class WeightScaleActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothHealthActivity";
    // Use the appropriate IEEE 11073 data types based on the devices used.
    // Below are some examples. Refer to relevant Bluetooth HDP specifications
    // for detail.
    // 0x1007 - blood pressure meter
    // 0x1008 - body thermometer
    // 0x100F - body weight scale
    private static final int HEALTH_WEIGHTSCALE_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE = 0x100F;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    private BluetoothDevice[] mAllBondedDevices;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private int mDeviceIndex = 0;
    private Resources mRes;
    private Messenger mHealthService;
    private boolean mHealthServiceBound;
    private double weight;
    private JSONObject jsonObj;
    public String weightStr;
    public boolean wtConnected = false;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String healthDeviceMac;

    // WeightScale
    private TextView weight_scale_value;
    private TextView weight_unit;

    private Handler mIncomingHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            // Application registration complete.
            case BtHealthDeviceService.STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG:
                System.out.println("In hdpacrtivity handleMessage");
                break;
            // Application unregistration complete.
            case BtHealthDeviceService.STATUS_HEALTH_APP_UNREG:
                break;
            // Reading data from HDP device.
            case BtHealthDeviceService.STATUS_READ_DATA:
                showIndicator(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.indicator_start_receive));

                break;

            // Finish reading data from HDP device.
            case BtHealthDeviceService.STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE:

                if (weight_scale_value != null) {
                    weight_scale_value.setText("" + weight);
                }

                dismissIndicator();
                // Send Data on Cloud
                sendData();
                break;

            case BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_MAC_ADDRESS:

                System.out.println("msg.obj.toString()" + msg.obj.toString());
                System.out.println("In mac address handle" + msg.arg1);
                healthDeviceMac = msg.obj.toString();
                break;
            // Channel creation complete. Some devices will automatically
            // establish connection.
            case BtHealthDeviceService.STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL:
                Log.d(TAG, "STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEl enabled");
                break;
            // Channel destroy complete. This happens when either the device
            // disconnects or there is extended inactivity.
            case BtHealthDeviceService.STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL:
                break;
            case BtHealthDeviceService.RECEIVED_WEIGHT:
                int weightt = msg.arg1;
                Log.i(TAG, "msg.arg1 @ sys is " + weightt);
                String weightStr = "" + weightt / 100 + "." + weightt % 100;
                weight = Double.parseDouble(weightStr);
                System.out.println("Weight is:" + weight);
                System.out.println("Weight:******");
                break;

            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    };
    private final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(mIncomingHandler);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // this code is for solving issue
        // android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        // Check for Bluetooth availability on the Android platform.
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bluetooth_not_available,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.weightscale_toggle);

        mRes = getResources();
        mHealthServiceBound = false;

        // Weight Scale
        // mWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
        LinearLayout weightLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.value_layout_weight);
        weight_scale_value = (TextView) weightLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.disp_data_ws_value_textview);
        weight_unit = (TextView) weightLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.disp_data_ws_unit_textview);

        Resources res = getBaseContext().getResources();
        weight_unit.setText("Kg");
        weight_unit.setText(res.getString(R.string.weightscale_unit));

        // Toggle button
        final ToggleButton weight_scale_connect_app_button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.weightscale_register_app_button);

        // Initiates application registration through {@link
        // BluetoothHDPService}.

        // Toggle Button Weightscale
        weight_scale_connect_app_button
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,
                            boolean checked) {
                        if (checked) {
                            sendMessage(
                                    BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP,
                                    HEALTH_WEIGHTSCALE_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE);
                            System.out.println("in Weight Toggle*****");

                        } else {
                            sendMessage(
                                    BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP,
                                    0);
                            System.out.println("in unregister Weight Toggle**");

                        }
                    }
                });

        if (weight_scale_connect_app_button.isChecked()) {
            sendMessage(BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP,
                    HEALTH_WEIGHTSCALE_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE);
            System.out.println("in Weight Toggle**--");

        } else {
            sendMessage(BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP, 0);
            System.out.println("in  unregister Weight Toggle**--");

        }

        // activity receiver not registered Exception
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

    // Sets up communication with {@link BluetoothHDPService}.
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mHealthServiceBound = true;
            System.out.println("In ServiceConnection onServiceConnected");
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null,
                    BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_REG_CLIENT);
            msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
            mHealthService = new Messenger(service);
            if (mHealthService == null) {
                System.out.println(">> mHealthService is null");
            }
            try {
                // 4
                System.out.println("in ServiceConnection try...");
                mHealthService.send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to register client to service.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            System.out.println(" in onServiceDisconnected ");
            mHealthService = null;
            mHealthServiceBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHealthServiceBound)
            unbindService(mConnection);
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If Bluetooth is not on, request that it be enabled.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ensures user has turned on Bluetooth on the Android device.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                initialize();
            } else {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used by {@link SelectDeviceDialogFragment} to record the bonded Bluetooth
     * device selected by the user.
     * 
     * @param position
     *            Position of the bonded Bluetooth device in the array.
     */
    public void setDevice(int position) {
        mDevice = this.mAllBondedDevices[position];
        mDeviceIndex = position;
    }

    private void connectChannel() {
        sendMessageWithDevice(BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_CONNECT_CHANNEL);
    }

    private void disconnectChannel() {
        sendMessageWithDevice(BtHealthDeviceService.MSG_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // Starts health service.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BtHealthDeviceService.class);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    // Intent filter and broadcast receive to handle Bluetooth on event.
    private IntentFilter initIntentFilter() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        return filter;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                    initialize();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    // Sends a message to {@link BluetoothHDPService}.
    private void sendMessage(int what, int value) {
        if (mHealthService == null) {
            System.out
                    .println("In HDP activity sendMessage -Health Service not connected.");

            Log.d(TAG, "Health Service not connected.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("hdp activity send message");
            System.out.println("what******" + what);
            System.out.println("value*****" + value);

            mHealthService.send(Message.obtain(null, what, value, 0));

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to reach service.");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Sends an update message, along with an HDP BluetoothDevice object, to
    // {@link BluetoothHDPService}. The BluetoothDevice object is needed by the
    // channel creation
    // method.
    private void sendMessageWithDevice(int what) {
        if (mHealthService == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Health Service not connected.");
            System.out.println("in sendMessageWithDevice");
            return;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("in sendMessageWithDevice try");

            mHealthService.send(Message.obtain(null, what, mDevice));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to reach service.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Dialog to display a list of bonded Bluetooth devices for user to select
     * from. This is needed only for channel connection initiated from the
     * application.
     */
    public static class SelectDeviceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        public static SelectDeviceDialogFragment newInstance(String[] names,
                int position) {
            SelectDeviceDialogFragment frag = new SelectDeviceDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putStringArray("names", names);
            args.putInt("position", position);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String[] deviceNames = getArguments().getStringArray("names");
            int position = getArguments().getInt("position", -1);
            if (position == -1)
                position = 0;
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(R.string.select_device)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    ((WeightScaleActivity) getActivity())
                                            .connectChannel();
                                }
                            })
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(deviceNames, position,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    ((WeightScaleActivity) getActivity())
                                            .setDevice(which);
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }

    private void sendData() {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        new RestConnection().execute();
    }

    private class RestConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public RestConnection() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String st = jsonObj.toString();
            String response = "";

            Log.i(TAG, st);

            JSONObject item = null;
            try {
                item = new JSONObject(st);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not parse malformed JSON:" + st);
            }

            if (item == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Null");
            }

            // doing the respective post
            try {

                // POST DATA
                String url = Constants.getDataPost();
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(
                        httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("siteId", "");
                if (wtConnected == true) {
                    json.put("patientId", 5);
                    json.put("deviceMACId", healthDeviceMac);
                    json.put("readingType", 103);
                    json.put("deviceData", Double.toString(weight));
                    json.put("deviceType", "WeightScale");

                }
                json.put("assetId", "");

                json.put("geoLocationLatitude", "");

                json.put("clientId", "");

                json.put("timeStamp", System.currentTimeMillis());

                json.put("deviceRawData", "");
                json.put("geoLocationLongitude", "");

                System.out.println("Json Is:" + json);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.i(TAG, "response "
                        + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                HttpEntity entityPost = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entityPost.getContent();
                String response1 = convertStreamToString(is);
                Log.i(TAG, "response message " + response1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Post error:Error");
                Log.i(TAG, "Weight" + response);
            }

            return response;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // Progress Dialog for Data Reading

    private Dialog progress;

    private void showIndicator(String message) {
        if (progress == null) {
            progress = new Dialog(WeightScaleActivity.this);
            // AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            progress.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
            progress.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            progress.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
        }

        setIndicatorMessage(message);

        if (!progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.show();
        }
    }

    private void setIndicatorMessage(String message) {
        if (progress == null) {
            return;
        }
        TextView syncMessages = (TextView) progress
                .findViewById(R.id.syncMessages1);

        if (message == null) {
            message = "";
        }

        if (syncMessages != null) {
            syncMessages.setText(message);
        }
    }

    private void dismissIndicator() {
        if (progress == null) {
            return;
        }

        progress.dismiss();
        progress = null;
    }

    // Are you sure you want to exit? Alert Box
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                WeightScaleActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Change this  'TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 'with
        'TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);'

Comment: and plz share your XML also where you have created tablayout